# Making XHTML file valid using regex

Tags: php, xml, regex, xhtml, simplexml

I'm trying to use PHP with SimpleXML to parse an XHTML file, however the file contains < and > signs which are not part of the markup and cause parsing to fail (opening and end tag mismatches).

How can I convert these to HTML entities before parsing without changing the file or affecting the markup?

Example:

```
<p> a < b </p>
```

Would become:

```
<p> a &lt; <b> </p>
```

Comment: you should consider to use http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php

Comment: Its generally bad practice to use a xml parser on a xhtml document, as its a rare sight that a page actually is valid xhtml. What is the purpose of wanting to parse the page via xml?

Comment: I want to parse a table of products from an xhtml page and store them in a database and wasn't aware of the DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile, however it seems to choke on < as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Jespersen already said, there is no good way to parse (invalid or valid) markup with regexes, at least not with PHP regexes.

That said, *if* you're only looking for a way to remove

- unbalanced angle brackets
- that are between valid tags
- which do not contain angle brackets somewhere inside their attribute values

then you might get away with doing this:

```
$intermediate = preg_replace('/(>[^<>]*)<([^<>]*<)/', '\1&lt;\2', $subject);
$result = preg_replace('/(>[^<>]*)>([^<>]*<)/', '\1&gt;\2', $intermediate);
```

but you'd have to run this several times until there are no more matches because this will only catch one stray `<` or `>` between tags at a time. It will also fail on pseudo-balanced brackets like `<p> a <> b </p>`.

Comment: Got away with your suggestion and using DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile instead of SimpleXML and it works a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well the short answer is: you can't parse html with regex.

Maybe you could try using another xml parser that doesnt' choke on the `<` and `>` ?

Better yet, don't try to parse an xhtml file as xml, since as you already point out yourself, it isn't really an xml file, and has illegal characters in it.